# Quick Sort Data in r and remove duplicates

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame in this format named `Test`

```
Names  Category Date        
Ashley  A       29/01  
Ashley  M       28/01    
Ashley  M       27/01   
Bob     A       16/01   
Charles M       12/01  
Mary    A       25/01  
Mary    M       27/01
```

I want to sort data frame by date and also pick only the most recent element in my data frame by removing duplicates.

So Output should be like

```
Name       Cat      Date    
Ashley     A        29/01  
Bob        A        16/01    
Charles    M        12/01  
Mary       M        27/01
```

Comment: What's the structure of `Test$Date`? If you could edit with the results of `dput(Test)`, it will be easier to see how your data is arranged (and thus what you need to do).

Answer (score 2):

In the order given by you, using only base:

```
ordered <- data[order(data$Date,decreasing=TRUE),]
unique <- ordered[!duplicated(ordered$Names),]
```

Assuming your data is a data.frame stored under "data".
Then the output is:

```
    Names Category  Date
1  Ashley        A 29/01
7    Mary        M 27/01
4     Bob        A 16/01
5 Charles        M 12/01
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Test)`), then `order` by 'Names' and 'Date' (after converting to `Date` class), and remove the duplicates with `!duplicated`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Test)[order(Names,-as.Date(paste0(Date, '/01'), 
                      '%d/%m/%y'))][!duplicated(Names)]
#     Names Category  Date
#1:  Ashley        A 29/01
#2:     Bob        A 16/01
#3: Charles        M 12/01
#4:    Mary        M 27/01
```

Or another option is `unique` with `by` option after `order`ing

```
unique(setDT(Test)[order(Names,-as.Date(paste0(Date,
                   '/01'), '%d/%m/%y'))], by = 'Names')
```

NOTE: It is not clear whether the 'Date' format is `%d/%m` or `%d/%y`.  The above code `paste` '01' and use the format `%d/%m/%y` (assuming that 'year' is missing).  If the 'month' is missing, use `%d/%y/%m` as format)

---

If we need to use `base R`, the equivalent method is

```
 i1 <- with(Test, order(Names, -as.numeric(as.Date(paste0(Date, 
                  '/01'), '%d/%m/%y'))))
 Test[i1,][!duplicated(Test$Names),]
 #     Names Category  Date
 #1  Ashley        A 29/01
 #4     Bob        A 16/01
 #5 Charles        M 12/01
 #7    Mary        M 27/01
```

NOTE: This is the same order as the expected output showed in the OP's post.

#### data

```
Test <- structure(list(Names = c("Ashley", "Ashley", "Ashley", "Bob", 
"Charles", "Mary", "Mary"), Category = c("A", "M", "M", "A", 
"M", "A", "M"), Date = c("29/01", "28/01", "27/01", "16/01", 
"12/01", "25/01", "27/01")), .Names = c("Names", "Category", 
"Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```